# Align and wrap imagebuttons in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a `linearlayout` that has `imagebuttons` aligned horizontally, at the bottom of the parent layout. This is exactly, what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is how I am doing it:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_1"
            android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_2"
            android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_3"
            android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried to give `weightsum` to the `linearlayout`, and assign `weights` to `imagebuttons`. But it stretches the aspect ratio of the drawables.

How should I use my layout to arrange them in the bottom of the view, evenly spaced, centrally placed and without any stretched out aspect ratios of drawables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve this one using LinearLayout try this one..

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
   <View android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="5"
         android:layout_height="1dip"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <View android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="1dip"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or if you are ok with relativelayout try this one...

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Linearlayout solution worked perfect. What is the difference between specifying the src and background in this case? Also, why do you have a View tag specifically in your first two imagebuttons?

Comment: @faizanjehangir src means source for the view.It will be first visible in that view.background means background of the view.it shown behind the assigned source image..

Comment: @faizanjehangir just take look on it...i assigned linearlayout weightsum as 10.In two Views divided the weightsum and pass those values as weight 5.Basically the view takes margin as first prefrences later it takes weightsum attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can try in two ways as bellow

1) layout_weight & weightSum

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="C" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

2) Either change to  'RelativeLayout'

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                      
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="C" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to used RelativeLayout like this.....

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_1"
        android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_2"
        android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_3"
        android:background="@drawable/_dashboard_3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/new_1"
                    android:src="@drawable/_dashboard_1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/new_2"
                    android:src="@drawable/_dashboard_2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/new_3"
                    android:src="@drawable/_dashboard_3"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I made the suggested change, still the same result, should I wrap each imagebutton inside another layout?

Comment: can you edit the post and show the change to be made?